# React Native Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've tried to get a minimal example of infinite scroll.
So I have this:

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image,
    ListView,
    } = React;

var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    }

];

var InfiniteScreen = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isLoadingTail: false,
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            })
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.getDataSource(data)
        });
    },
    renderRow: function (item) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image style={{width: 80, height: 80}} source={{uri: 'http:' + item.profile_picture.href}}/>
            </View>
        );
    },
    onEndReached: function () {
        console.log('onEndReached', this.state.isLoadingTail);
        if (this.state.isLoadingTail) {
            // We're already fetching
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            isLoadingTail: true
        });

        this.setState({
            isLoadingTail: false,
            dataSource: this.getDataSource(data)
        });
    },
    getDataSource: function (users):ListView.DataSource {
        return this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(users);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <View>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
                />
            </View>);
    }
});
```

If I scroll to the very bottom, onEndReached() is fired, but the new data doesn't appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You always clone your data source with the same data, so nothing new appears. Here is a working example (add new data via `concat`):

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image,
    ListView,
    } = React;

var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "profile_picture": {
            "href": "//like1.r.worldssl.net/ui_big/1305634.jpg"
        }
    }

];

var InfiniteScreen = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isLoadingTail: false,
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            })
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this._data = [];
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.getDataSource(data)
        });
    },
    renderRow: function (item) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image style={{width: 80, height: 80}} source={{uri: 'http:' + item.profile_picture.href}}/>
            </View>
        );
    },
    onEndReached: function () {
        console.log('onEndReached', this.state.isLoadingTail);
        if (this.state.isLoadingTail) {
            // We're already fetching
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            isLoadingTail: true
        });

        this.setState({
            isLoadingTail: false,
            dataSource: this.getDataSource(data)
        });
    },
    getDataSource: function (users):ListView.DataSource {
        this._data = this._data.concat(users);
        return this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this._data);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
                />
            </View>);
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

so the problems is here

```
    this.setState({
        isLoadingTail: true
    });

    this.setState({
        isLoadingTail: false,
        dataSource: this.getDataSource(data)
    });
```

Comment: Answer by @vkurchatkin is better and it definitely solves the problem. But, anyway, code which I pointed at is broken. Component isn't going to re-render after each setState

Comment: how this can answer the question?

Comment: It doesn't, I guess at that time I didn't have enough karma to post comments, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this solution for very long time. Finally I came up with this light weight library :-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-infinite-scroll

```
import InfiniteListView from 'rn-infinite-scroll';

<InfiniteListView
    data ={this.state.items}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    canLoad={this.canLoad()}
    isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
    onLoad={this.onLoad}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) is currently Deprecated. You will have to use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) or [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). You can find an example of infinite scroll using FlatList in this answer for another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710224/7477198.