# React native infinite scroll with flatlist

Tags: react-native

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rY0braBBlgw
When I scroll down it sends the request then it gets stuck in a loop and just requests and requests. I think this is a problem with the scrollview in the listview.

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's a debugging question that doesn't include any code in the question itself. Asking us to debug code that's hosted off-site isn't accepted here; asking us to debug code from a *YouTube video* certainly isn't. Although it's not a perfect match for this case, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1709587 for some discussion of why.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure if you were able to resolve this but I was having the same problem and I am adding what worked well for me.

> ***onEndReachedThreshold***=>**onEndThreshold**

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          title={
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'left'}}> {item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>
          }
          subtitle={
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>{item.email}</Text>
          }
          avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
          containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
        />
      )}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      keyExtractor={item => item.email}
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
      onEndThreshold={0}

    />
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: No I did the same but, the onEndReached executes infinitely. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
     <FlatList
          data={this.state.storesList}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderItem(item, index)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
          onEndReached={this.fetchMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        />


renderFooter = () => {
    if (this.state.refreshing) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };


  fetchMore = () => {
    if (this.state.refreshing){
      return null;
    }
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => {
        return { refreshing: true, pageNum: prevState.pageNum + 1 };
      },
      () => {
        this.sendAPIRequest(null , true);
      }
    );
  };
```

The reason I used the following in the fetchMore function:

```
if (this.state.refreshing){
      return null;
    }
```

Is because when you setState to the pageNum it calls the render() function and then the fetchMore called again. This is written to prevent it.
In addition, I set:

```
refreshing: false
```

after the sendAPIRequest is done.
Pay attention about onEndReachedThreshold in FlatList:

> How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the
>   bottom edge of the list must be from the end of the content to trigger
>   the onEndReached callback.

Meaning in my example (0.1) means: when you reach 10% of items from the bottom, the fetchMore callback is called. In my example, I have 10 items in the list, so when the last item is visible, fetchMore is called.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the code I've left below allows you to continue scrolling through a fixed set of `data` props. When you reach the last index, it basically wraps around to the beginning. I've achieved this by appending a copy of the first element of the supplied `data` to the end of the `FlatList`; when the user scrolls this into view, we can safely reset the scroll offset.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class InfiniteFlatList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this._flatList = null;
  }

  getWrappableData = (data) => {
    return [...data, data[0]];
  }

  render = () => (
    <FlatList
      { ...this.props }
      ref={ (el) => this._flatList = el }
      onLayout={ ({nativeEvent}) => {
        const {width, height} = nativeEvent.layout;
        this.setState({
          width, height
        });
      } }
      onScroll={ ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        const { x } = nativeEvent.contentOffset;
        if(x === (this.props.data.length * this.state.width)) {
          this._flatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, animated: false});
        }
      } }
      data={ this.getWrappableData(this.props.data) }
      pagingEnabled={true}
    />
  )

};

InfiniteFlatList.defaultProps = { };
InfiniteFlatList.propTypes = { };
```

This assumes you want to scroll horizontally.

It probably isn't perfect; there is likely a better technique out there which uses `FlatList`'s `onEndReached` callback, however this only seemed to fire once througohout. By polling the scroll offset of the `FlatList`, we can fire off our own equivalent as many times as needed. If you specify a `getItemLayout` prop, you'll be able to use `scrollToIndex({index, animated?})` instead.

**Aug. 5, 2019 update**

On React native 0.60, one should use scrollToOffset as:

```
 this._flatList.scrollToOffset({offset: 0, animated: false});
```