# React Native bidirectional horizontal FlatList loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to create a loop in `FlatList` so if we have three slides, user can scroll something like this:

```
...

1

2

3

1

2

3

...
```

Please consider that the `FlatList` is bidirectional so user can scroll like:

```
...

2

1

3

2

1

...
```

---

I tried to use:

```
onEndReachedThreshold={0}
onEndReached={() =>
  this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ x: 0, animated: false })
}
```

But this is not smooth and also it's not bidirectional!

Any idea?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338832/8434189

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe - Not working!

Comment: Please post your complete code including FlatList definition.