# How to make this flatlist infinite scrollable in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

export default class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      data: [

        {id:1,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", date:"2019-03-25 09:12:00", color:"#228B22", completed:1},

        {id:2,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis.",     date:"2019-03-25 10:23:00", color:"#FF00FF", completed:0},

        {id:3,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies dnec.", date:"2019-03-25 11:45:00", color:"#4B0082", completed:1},

        {id:4,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputdate.", date:"2019-03-25 09:27:00", color:"#20B2AA", completed:0},

        {id:5,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tirr.", date:"2019-03-25 08:13:00", color:"#000080", completed:0},

        {id:6,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas st.", date:"2019-03-25 10:22:00", color:"#FF4500", completed:1},

        {id:7,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", date:"2019-03-25 13:33:00", color:"#FF0000", completed:0},

        {id:8,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae .", date:"2019-03-25 11:56:00", color:"#EE82EE", completed:0},

        {id:9,  type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.", date:"2019-03-25 15:00:00", color:"#6A5ACD", completed:0},

        {id:10, type:"Invester",name:"Vishal Jain", description:" Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augues aasde.", date:"2019-03-25 12:27:00", color:"#DDA0DD", completed:0},

      ]

    };

  }


  clickEventListener = (item) => {

    Alert.alert("Item selected: "+item.description)

}

  __getCompletedIcon = (item) => {

 if(item.completed == 1) {

      return "https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/checkmark.png";

    } else {

      return "https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/delete-sign.png";

    }

  }

  __getDescriptionStyle = (item) => {

    if(item.completed == 1) {

      return {textDecorationLine:"line-through", fontStyle:'italic', color:"#808080"};

    }

  } 

  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <FlatList 

          style={styles.tasks}

          columnWrapperStyle={styles.listContainer}

          data={this.state.data}

          keyExtractor= {(item) => {

            return item.id;

          }}

          renderItem={({item}) => {

          return (

            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.card, {borderColor:item.color}]} onPress={() =>{this.clickEventListener(item)}}>

              {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: this.__getCompletedIcon(item)}}/> */}

              <View style={styles.cardContent}>

                <Text style={{fontSize:18,flex:1,color:"#000",fontWeight:'bold',}} >{item.name} ({item.type})</Text>

                <Text style={[styles.description, this.__getDescriptionStyle(item)]}>{item.description}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.date}>{item.date}</Text>

              </View>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}}

          />

      </View>

    );

  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container:{

    flex:1,

    marginTop:20,

    backgroundColor:"#eeeeee"

  },

  tasks:{

    flex:1,

  },

  cardContent: {

    marginLeft:20,

    marginTop:10,

  },

  image:{

    width:25,

    height:25,

  },


  card:{

    shadowColor: '#00000021',

    shadowOffset: {

      width: 0,

      height: 6,

    },

    shadowOpacity: 0.37,

    shadowRadius: 7.49,

    elevation: 12,


    marginVertical: 10,

    marginHorizontal:20,

    backgroundColor:"white",

    flexBasis: '46%',

    padding: 10,

    flexDirection:'row',

    flexWrap: 'wrap',

    borderLeftWidth:6,

  },



  description:{

    fontSize:18,

    flex:1,

    color:"#008080",

    fontWeight:'bold',

  },

  date:{

    fontSize:14,

    flex:1,

    color:"#696969",

    marginTop:5

  },

});
```

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6, search `Infinite Scroll` in this nice article..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native infinite scroll with flatlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385433/react-native-infinite-scroll-with-flatlist)