# Create a bidirectional repeating/looping infinite scrollView in react native

Tags: react-native, react-component, react-native-scrollview

I want to create a scroll that repeats itself, again and again, i.e. when I keep scrolling to the top I reach the last row and when I scroll to the bottom I reach the first row again.

I have tried searching components for the same, but the best I could find were these -

[react-native-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-scroll) and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262404/react-native-infinite-scroll) but both of them only tell about how can I load more data when I reach the ScrollView or ListView end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched a lot for this type component but couldn't find any, so I created my own component from scratch using FlatList, and also [published it to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll), so anyone can install it using

```
npm install react-native-infinite-looping-scroll
```

in your react native project directory.

The component is still in beta so don't expect very good performance from it. But the component is still pretty basic and there's a lot of scope for improvement so anyone who wants to contribute to it can submit a PR [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll).