# Infinite loop scroll with list of react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to build an infinite loop scroll with the list of react-native as a picture? I think this question will duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149784/create-a-bidirectional-repeating-looping-infinite-scrollview-in-react-native), and they recommend to use this lib [npm lnk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll). but this lib still low trick when I tested it. 
and anyone has any solutions or recommends sth about this. 
[image]

Comment: You can try this [react-native-snap-carosel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel)

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq: thank to comment, I think this lib does not match my requirement, cuz it like render one page per screen, but my requirement there are several items in the screen.

Comment: Dear @LeangSocheat did you find any solution?