# How to make a flat list scroll Infinitely in React Native With a Finite Amount of data in Array

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have **flat list horizontally set**
with **data of 11 items coming from an array**, which is **fixed and never changes**

> **what I want is when user reaches at the end of flat list while scrolling, the data should remain the same but the first item should
>   show up in the last and then so on**

here is what I have tried so far

```
  <FlatList
        {...this.props}
        ref={ref => {
          this.infListRef = ref;
        }}
        data={this.props.data}
        onScrollEndDrag={this.handleScroll}
        initialScrollIndex={0}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        renderItem={this.props.renderItem}
        onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => this.checkScroll(nativeEvent)}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, implementing `onScroll` usage is when you want to be noticed when the actually scroll related to the scroll position (aminations for instance). When you would like to be notified when the user reaches, or about to reach, to the end of the `FlatList`.

You should implement `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold` to handle a better user experience when the user reaches the threshold.

The new data you're getting from the source (server or no matter wherefrom) should be concatenated to existing `this.props.data`

See good blog post - https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-an-infinite-scroll-list-in-react-native

And this SO answers - [React Native Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262404/react-native-infinite-scroll)

My solution refers to pagination because infinite scroll is a private case of pagination, it's the exact same approach.

Comment: brother thanks for the answer but the question has a requirement that data is FINITE! not paginated! only 11 items to repeated

Comment: Infinite is a **private case** of pagination, that's exactly the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `image` or `video` list
One other approach which is kind a hack and an easy one is using [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/)

```
<Carousel
      ref={ (c) => { this._carousel = c; } }
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      onSnapToItem={this.handleSnapToItem.bind(this)}
      sliderWidth={360}
      itemWidth={256}
      layout={'default'}
      firstItem={0}
      itemHeight={20}
      sliderHeight={20}
      loop
      vertical
      loopClonesPerSide={100}
    />
```

Example:
https://snack.expo.io/@kurtesy/react-native-snap-carousel-example

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using `onEndReached` method of `Flatlist`.

This is the idea behind answer.

```
    state = {
      data: []   //your initial data
    }


    <Flatlist
     {…this.props}
     extraData={this.state}
     onEndReached = {() => {
     this.setState((prevState) =>{
        data: […prevState,this.state.data]
     )}}
    />
```

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question. Instead of looping items of finite data, it adds data over and over (making it infinite) leading to memory leaks. Try for one to display the actual amount of items you have, or add some items after a few scrolls, and see what happens

Comment: Yes this caused me the issue with data but can you suggest some better solution ?